# I can't show an html page

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have to develop a project for college using Spring. I started watching some tutorials and I can't show an html page. I do the same but it returns only one string.
I'm using visual studio code.

Controller:

```
package com.example.springteste.controllers;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ProductController {

    @GetMapping("/formulario")
    public String formulario() 
    {
        return "form";
    }
}
```

My view is just inside templates

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <main>
    <section id="sectionProduct">
        <div>
            <div id="sectionProduct-title">
                <h1>
                    Título
                </h1>
            </div>

            <div id="sectionProduct-form">
                <form action="">
                    <div class="sectionProduct-form-inputLabel">
                        <input type="text" id="title" name="title">
                        <label for="title">
                            Título
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>

</body>
</html>
```

I believe something is missing. I am a beginner in java and spring

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a view name from the controller method handler - you have to use `@Controller` annotation. Also make sure you put your views into the correct directory, according to your view resolver configuration.

About `@RestController` - as the name suggests, it shall be used in case of REST style controllers i.e. handler methods shall return the JSON/XML response directly to the client rather using view resolvers.

In your case the handler method will return `"form"` to the client.